# How can I find out how much data an svn checkout or svn switch will use?

Tags: svn

Today I am working with only a mobile data connection. I am wondering if there is a way to determine how much data will need to be downloaded as the result of a switch, or, in some cases, a checkout. Preferably before those operations are performed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature estimating it beforehand build into SVN. 
You could roughly estimate it by making a diff (for switch) and summing up the size of files in your folder structure, however I doubt it is near the transfersize as depending on protocol you may or may not use compression, which makes all calculation basically meaningless.

A switch is usually faster as only diffs will be transferred to your client (this is only true if both folders are somewhat similar and share the same history).